# How do you identify nondeliverable swap

Tags: fx, interest-rate-swap, rates, fxo, ndf

what is unique about NDS transactions, how can I identify them using certain parameters or attributes specific to NDS?

Comment: what system? I mean the most obvious difference is that they are non deliverable. So if you have a flag that states deliverable or not, you have it. Bloomberg for example, if you have tickers like IRSWNI10 writes directly in the description that it is a NDOIS (ND OIS swap). SWPM also directly shows NDIRS at the very top (if it is none).

Comment: wallstreet system (WSS) for FX